# JVM выполняет код дважды

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, jvm

```
Из основного класса выполняю в методе onCreate
 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);'
```

В activity_main подключаю класс для отрисовки игрового поля + некоторые вычисления:

```
  <com.example.sapeg.myapplication.MyDraw
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"/>
```

Вопрос: почему JVM производит дважды вычисления находящиеся в классе MyDraw( дважды вызывает метод onDraw). Это при первом проходе далее вызывается по разу за запрос.
   Я хоть и написал "многопоточность", но через LogCat выяснилось что всё это выполняется в одном потоке "main".

Comment: Метод  `onDraw` вызывается каждый раз, как система посчитает нужным перерисовать объект, а лишние вычисления в этом методе уже на Вашей совести.

Comment: Есть ли возможность отследить места, откуда система вызывает `onDraw`?

Comment: Зачем? В `onDraw` Вы должны нарисовать Ваш контент в предоставленный `Canvas` и это всё, что Вам от него нужно. Вызывается он когда произошло событие, затрагивающее Вашу вью (появление на экране, клик, сдвиг, чих, пых)), а также по Вашей просьбе: `view.invalidate()`

Comment: Так я там и рисую контент. Вывожу фигуру в random-месте. Но т.к. `onDraw` запускается дважды, фигура перемещается из нужного мне места.

Comment: Вынесите расчёт местоположения в другой метод, запомните результат расчёта в полях класса, а в `onDraw` берите значения из этих полей.  Вызывайте расчёт по логике смены местоположения, а не из `onDraw`. Тогда оно не будет зависеть от его вызовов. Например, первоначальное положение можно рассчитать в конструкторе, а дальше по клику кнопки или как там у Вас должно быть.

Comment: @woesss спасибо. В общем пока решил сие установкой костылей. Поставил счётчик и вывожу картинку на счёт 2)).

Comment: @sapeg да, чтобы узнать откуда вызывают `onDraw` поставьте брейкпоинт в метод и смотрите стектрейс.